# Git diff show nothing

Tags: git, github, diff

I have a private github repo and cloned it to my local machine. I created a file `tmp.tmp` with some random content on my local machine, commited it and pushed into github, then I changed this file in github via github website. I see, that content in my local repo and in github is different. I typed `git diff origin/main` and this command showed me nothing. But `git pull` correctly download changes from the github. 
How can I see difference between github and my local repo ?
P
P.S. I have a branch `dev` and it has a lot of differences in github and local repo. `git diff origin/dev` shows this differences.

Comment: Have you checked-out local/main on your local machine? It may be that you are checked-out on origin/main and you are trying to diff between the same two branches (as you've pulled the changes from GitHub already)

Comment: Nothing happens until you say `git fetch`.

Comment: @VladNitu yes, I am at local branch now:  
`$ git branch -a  
  dev  
* main  
  remotes/origin/dev  
  remotes/origin/main`

Comment: @matt he already `git pulled`, which is `git fetch && git merge`

Comment: @mcjohn974 make sure you `git pull` when checked-out on `origin/main`, as pull command only 'Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch'

Comment: If you want to fetch all remote branches (so not only the one you are checked-out on), go for `git pull --all`. More info about git-pull comand in their [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: @VladNitu I don't wont to pull. I want just check if my local ```main``` differs with the ```main``` in the github

Comment: @VladNitu matt is correct. OP checked the diff and saw nothing, and *then* did a pull (which fetched). At that point a diff would still show nothing because it's up to date. Had OP fetched first without pulling, the diff would have shown the differences. Actually, I just made this the answer, because it is the answer. Credit to matt though...

Comment: @TTT oh I see, I misread the task. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Yeah, roger that @TTT, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you didn't see a difference is because you hadn't fetched at the time you ran the diff command. Fetch will update your remote tracking branch (`origin/main`) without updating your local branch. Once you pulled you fetched and also updated your local branch with the remote branch, so once again you were in sync.

Next time, issue `git fetch` and then run your diff to see the difference. If you like it, then you can run `git merge` to "pull" that into your local branch.

Here's an example diagram of the states to help visualize it. You ran the `diff` at "Initial" to compare `main` and `origin/main`, so you couldn't see the remote changes yet. Even after state "Pull" you still wouldn't have been able to see the diff. Only after "Fetch" would it have worked (if you hadn't pulled yet):

```
            main       origin/main       remote origin/main
Initial     X          X                 Y
Fetch       X          Y                 Y
Pull        Y          Y                 Y
```

**Side Note:** I rarely ever use the `pull` command anymore, and this is one of the reasons for it. I like to be able to see what's changed before I "pull" (actually `merge`) it in.